# Vibrating mesh transducer not nebulizing

Tags: transducer, mesh-analysis

Currently, I am trying to use a vibrating mesh transducer that's regulated using a high-voltage driver (100±5kHz, 65±5V), that's Grove Water Atomizer board.

Two problems have been arising, which I've been trying to address. Either the transducer heats up enormously (overheats) or it has difficulty atomizing (the liquid basically seeps through the holes and puddles on the "output side" of the transducer). Would anyone have any ideas as to what is causing this?

Comment: maybe your drive is at the wrong frequency.

Answer (score 0):

There is an input side and an output side to mesh/ring transducers. Try turning yours over. The holes in the mesh are conical, with the larger diameter towards the supply. 
Also, make sure you are driving the transducer at its resonant frequency.